# Is there a way of only allowing a particular player to use a particular tool or item in Minecraft adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minehut

I want to know if there is a way of only allowing particular players to use specific items in Minecraft Adventure mode?

My idea is to create an adventure mode Map, and I want to have classes. So only an Archer can use a bow, and only a Knight can use a sword and so on. This is for a Minehut server, using Minecraft Java 1.20.1.

Comment: One hack solution might be to make it so only [class] players can hold the item. I'd do that by checking to see if illegal player/item pairs exist, then wiping the item from their inventory and spawning an equivalent one.

Comment: You can add a tag to the players, like: <Player> tag: Ranger. Then you check that the player holding the item has the correct tag.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with **tags**. For instance, you can use `/tag [selector] add Archer`.

For each class, place a **repeating, always active** command block and enter this command:

```
clear @a[tag=!Archer] bow
```

Replace 'Archer' with each class (keep the '!'), and change the item to whichever item is specific to that class.

You can assign each player a class using `/tag [selector] add [class]`. To remove a class from a player, use `/tag [selector] remove Archer`. If a player doesn't have a class, but has the class's specific item, then it will be cleared from their inventory.

Comment: This would work but ideally the items would still exist and be unusable, not vanish entirely.